# Rails - has_many through relation saved without saving parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am using Rails 4.2 and recently tried using has_many through relationship in my model. I am facing an issue while updating a record and not sure how to handle it.
Consider below are my models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor: name

  validates :name, :presence => true
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :post_tags, :autosave => false

  def tags_used
    self.tags.collect(&:name).join(',')
  end

  def tags_used=(list)
    self.tags = list.present? ? Tag.where(:name => list.split(/\s*,\s*/)) : [ ]
  end
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :posts, :through => :post_tags
end

class PostTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

Now if i update an existing Post through below code

```
@post = Post.find(1)
@post.name = nil
@post.tags_used = ["rails","ruby"]
@post.save
```

The post would fail validation since name cannot be nil. But the post_tag records are getting saved.

I tried <<  and replace instead of = but it didn't help.

How to make sure that post_tag records are saved only if post record is saved

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap this code in transaction:

```
@post = Post.find(1)
@post.name = nil
@post.transaction do
  @post.tags_used = ["rails","ruby"]
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless @post.save
  # or just @post.save!
end
```

Comment: thanks @faron. I will check transactions. But then what is the use of <<  and autosave => false

Comment: Autosave will call `save` on loaded records when `parent.save` is called. Ex. `post = Post.first; post.tags.to_a; post.save` will call `save` on each tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transactions in time to save the post.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: thanks @edvin. I will check transactions. But then what is the use of "<<" and "autosave => false"

Answer (score 0):

When you use
self.tags = [TagsCollection] or self.tags << Tag
This will directly save the associated tags on the post. Thus you tags are saved here.

and when you call @post.save it will run the validations and show you the errors.

You can try using nested attributes for that or use self.tags.build in this case so that tags are saved when the parent is being saved.